# Can I pass an array to a php function that accepts an infinite number of arguments, in PHP 5.5 or earlier?

Tags: php

Given this example existing function (presumably written prior to PHP5.6);

```
function sum()
{
    $acc = 0;
    foreach (func_get_args() as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}
```

in PHP5.6 we can do this;

```
$values = array(1, 2, 3);
echo sum(...$values);
```

Can I pass an array in a similar fashion prior to 5.6?

Comment: [call_user_func_array('sum', $values)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: Perfect. Can you post as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP uses [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to pass variadic arguments in PHP versions prior to 5.6

```
$values = array(1, 2, 3);
echo call_user_func_array('sum', $values);
```

You should take note that PHP 5.4 and earlier always passes the array variables as a reference (which is a potential gotcha I ran across back in the day). That methodology has been removed in 5.5 and should not be used as it is deprecated since 5.3